# Find the dictionary keys that are present in the list

Tags: python

I am new to python object oriented programming. I am trying to solve a problem where I have to define a class , create a method , write the code inside it and then create a object and call that method. I am a little confused on how to go forward with it.

Example : {1:'A',2:'B}
L : [1,2,3,4]

Find the dictionary keys that are present in the list (without using for loop)

Comment: have you tried anything so far? what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another simple approach can be to use [intersection()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
my_dict = {1: 'A', 2: 'B'}
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

output = set(my_dict).intersection(my_list)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def match_keys(dct, lst):
    matches = list()
    
    for key in dct.keys():
        if key in lst:
            matches.append(key)
    
    return matches
```

Without for loop, you can use `filter`:

```py
output = list(filter(lambda elem: elem in list(dct.keys()), lst))
```